# Supernova styles missing?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I was viewing [this page](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website-design) and noticed that one question with 187k views didn't look like it had that many views based on the coloring - it had the same color as questions with low views. Upon inspection it had the following styles:

```
.supernova {
    color: #777;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

**These are the exact same as the default styles on `.views`**.

Is this supposed to be the case? Other SE websites usually have a darker red color for this class.

P.S. The color difference between `.warm` and `.hot` is very little, I had to really look close to tell the difference...

Edit: This is still around a month later

<sub>For reference about class naming for view counts, see [this Meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247552/215485).</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed with the April 2015 [updates to the site](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2495/8708).

[image: screenshot of fix]